# Azure load balancer rejecting requests after timeout

Tags: azure, mercurial, timeout, migration, azure-virtual-network

I'm investigating switching to Azure from AWS and have started running into a few issues regarding the default 4 minute timeout at the loadbalancer level. They seem to have recently made some changes to where you can now configure this value to a maximum of 30 minutes (http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/08/14/new-configurable-idle-timeout-for-azure-load-balancer/), but that's besides the point.

The issue is currently manifesting itself as I try to clone my hg repository to my VM instance. The repo is fairly large and ~15 minutes into cloning, the transfer completes, all network activity ceases, processing of the repo begins, and I almost immediately get the following error message:

"abort: error: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because
connected host has failed to respond"

I assume this is happening because of the LB timeout, although I would have expected it to happen 4 minutes after the hg cloning network activity stopped, not immediately afterwards.

The concerning part (and the core of my question) is that after I get this error message and I immediately try to clone again, I immediately get the following message again:

"abort: error: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because
connected host has failed to respond"

**The LB seems to be immediately rejecting my request after the timeout occurred!!! If I wait 10-20 minutes, I'm able to attempt to clone again.** If I were to guess, maybe this is an anti-DOS'ing mechanism? 
My questions are:

- Is my speculation correct?
- Is there anything I can do to modify this 'rejection/blocking' behavior immediately after a timeout occurs?
- Has anyone else seen this 'rejection/blocking' behavior immediately after a timeout occurs?

The primary usecase for the project I'm working on involves uploading large files (up to 100mb) and if a client surpasses the allotted timeout window, I don't want them to be prevented from accessing my services.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest re-examining all the machines participating in load balancing.  It sounds like the load balancer determines that the incoming packets are a new conversation, which provokes host selection and usually sends you to a machine other than the one you were just talking to, but some hosts participating in LB are not listening on the right ports for your service.  Service-level monitoring should catch this, if it's been configured yet, but you mentioned this is a new implementation.

The use pattern you described above can also be explained by getting a good machine the first time, then a bad machine for repo processing, then a bad machine on your retry.

Comment: There's only one machine that will answer for this VIP behind the LB. The loadbalancer I'm referring to is the the one inside Microsoft Azure's data center that routes to my VM instance - I have no control over the LB in question.

Comment: If there's only one VIP participant and its connection policy appears to be changing, you have a paradox on your hands.  Time to revisit basic assumptions -- if you can get to the server taking these calls and get a network trace of this experience, you'll be able to see whether that second connection for repo processing is _really_ going to that machine.  If it's not, you still won't know where the traffic _is_ going, but you can raise the issue with Azure support once you're armed with that evidence.

Comment: What is your recommendation for capturing this trace? Traceroute is disabled in the Azure datacenters. (And ping.... I'm not sure why these decisions were made by Azure architects, but that's besides the point)

Comment: Is the server completely abstracted away from you? If you can connect to it over RDP, you can capture traffic details locally using Network Monitor or Wireshark.